# How can I preserve the surface area of a mesh while editing it?

Tags: modeling, constraints

I'm trying to model a coat and I'm having difficulty creating folds while preserving the surface area of the mesh. Is there some sort of way to restrain the amount edited within the original surface area?

Comment: Check out Blender's [cloth brush](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+cloth+brush).